# Changing the cmd window title (VB.net vs PowerShell)

Tags: vb.net, powershell, cmd, titlebar

My goal is to run a third-party application though the cmd shell. My VB program will start multiple instances and I like to set the cmd title to keep track of those multiple windows. I'm running into the following issue: when I change the title using VB, the change is not consistent. The new title is changed back to the default title, as soon as you use a copy/paste function in this window or click anywhere in the cmd window. Here is the VB code I use:

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lpString As String) As Integer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim h_wnd As Integer
        Dim proc As New Process
        proc = Process.Start("cmd.exe")
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
        h_wnd = proc.MainWindowHandle
        SetWindowText(h_wnd, "Test Text")
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I do the same thing through PowerShell, the rename *is* consistent. Here's the PS code I use

```
Add-Type -Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace WT {
   public class Temp {
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      public static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string lpString); 
   }
}
"@

$titletext = "Test Text"
    # Start a thread job to change the window title to $titletext
    $null = Start-ThreadJob { param( $rawUI, $windowTitle )
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    if ( $rawUI.WindowTitle -ne $windowTitle ) {
        $rawUI.WindowTitle = $windowTitle
    }
    }-ArgumentList $host.ui.RawUI, $titletext
echo $rawUI
    & 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe'
```

The problem is that I won't be able to use PowerShell, because part of the parameters parsed to the script is a password and PowerShell logs all entries in the Windows Powershell log, including the password.
I can't explain why the title change is persistent in PS and why it isn't in VB. Does anybody has an idea?
Thanks for any help in advance!

Kind regards,
Eric

*Extra code added, to give an example of my rename issue in VB:*

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lpString As String) As Integer
    Public Shared proc As New Process
    Public Shared h_wnd As Integer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        proc = Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k title My new title & powershell.exe")
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        h_wnd = proc.MainWindowHandle
        SetWindowText(h_wnd, "My new title")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Often you have to use Out-Null in PS to supress output.  Try adding to following : }-ArgumentList $host.ui.RawUI, $titletext | Out-Null

Comment: Hi @jdweng Maybe I was not clear: the PS is in fact working as expected. The rename works and is persistent. The rename with the VB code however is not.

Comment: I know.  Is the issue with the log files the login or the output?  Using Out-Null may stop the log message from having the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To set `cmd.exe`'s window title *once*, on startup:**

You can use `cmd.exe`'s CLI and its internal `title` command to persistently set the new console window's title:

```vb
proc = Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k title Test Text")
```

- `/k` creates an interactive `cmd.exe` session that stays open, and accepts a startup command (by contrast, `/c` executes the given startup command and then exits - see `cmd /?`)
- `title` sets the window title; do *not* enclose the argument in `"..."`, because the `"` will then be *retained* in the title. If your title contains `cmd.exe` *metacharacters* (other than spaces), such as `&`, escape them individually with `^`.
- A title set this way stays in effect *unless overwritten by a console application called from the session, while that application is running*.

  - If a console application does *not* modify the title, `cmd.exe` appends the invocation command line to its title, for the duration of the execution (e.g., `Test Text - some.exe foo bar`), but only in an *interactive* session, i.e. one launched with `cmd /k` (plus a startup command) or without any arguments; by contrast, this does *not* happen with `cmd /c`.
  - Once the application exits, the original title is restored, in either case.

---

**If you need to undo the effects of a title modification performed by a console application *while it is running***, then an asynchronous approach seems like the only option, which cannot be achieved with `cmd.exe` alone, because it doesn't support background jobs.

- *Both* setting the original window title with `title` *and*
  your asynchronous VB.NET approach of calling `SetWindowText()` later actions are needed, because when you use `SetWindowText()` to change the console window title later, `cmd.exe` doesn't realize that that happened and reverts to *its* title on interacting with the window, such as when selecting text, which is what you saw.
- You can make your `SetWindowText()` approach more deterministic by *waiting in a loop* until the title actually changes from its startup value, and *then* make the call, analogous to what your PowerShell code does, only from *outside* the process.

Because as noted above, using `/k` makes `cmd.exe` *append the invocation command line* to its window title while a program launched from it is running, so that on *interacting* with the window, you won't *just* see `Test Text`, but something like `Test Text - some.exe foo bar`.
Therefore, call with `cmd /c`, and make a *nested* `cmd /k` call *after* executing your console application in order to *then* enter an interactive session; e.g.: (`some.exe` is a *sample* executable name, and `foo` and `bar` are *sample* arguments - adapt as needed):

```vb
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c title Test Text & some.exe foo bar & cmd /k")
```

Alternatively, if you simply want to keep the window open *until the user presses a key* (i.e. if you don't need an *interactive* `cmd.exe` session after execution ends), replace `cmd / k` with `pause`; or simply omit a final command if the window doesn't need to stay open after termination at all.

To put it all together (again, change the sample `some.exe` call as needed):

```vb
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lpString As String) As Integer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim proc As New Process
        ' Note: special chars. such as "&", ">", "|", ... would require "^"-escaping
        Dim customTitle As String = "Test Text"
        proc = Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c title " & customTitle & " & some.exe foo bar & cmd /k")
        ' Wait until the console application has changed the window title.
        Do
          ' Note: It is assumed that 300 msecs. are enough for the intitial `title` command to take effect.
          Thread.Sleep(300)
        Loop Until Not proc.MainWindowTitle.StartsWith(customTitle)
        ' The console application has changed the window title,
        ' change it back.
        SetWindowText(proc.MainWindowHandle, customTitle)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note:

- You may want to implement a *timeout* for the loop that waits for the window title to change, so that you don't get stuck in an endless loop if your console application fails to launch, for instance.
- The assumption is that your console application only changes its window title *once*, on startup.

  - *Update*: You report that this is apparently *not* true, so you'd need a loop that keeps monitoring for title changes *throughout the life time of the console application*, which in turn requires *creating a dedicated thread* that performs this monitoring, so as not to block your GUI.
  - It is unclear why, but you state that with your PowerShell approach a *one-time* restoration of the original title is sufficient (in that case, you *do* properly set the console window title, due to running *inside* the console); therefore, it's simplest to stick with your PowerShell approach, whose password-logging problem you can avoid by providing the password via an *environment variable* that you must set in your VB.NET application first, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75474953/45375) to your follow-up question.

Comment: Hi @mklement0, that won't work in my case. My VB application will (later down the road) start an external (character based) application, which will run inside the cmd window. In that case the /k switch will no longer work, because it's only valid for cmd.exe

Comment: @EricvanLoon, it will start a console application _how and where_? In the previously launched `cmd.exe` session? How would you do that if not via a startup command? E.g. `proc = Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k title Test Text & som.exe foo bar")`

Comment: Hi @mklement0 What I meant was that I'm currently testing with cmd.exe, but later I will use a different application (let's call it MyApp.exe), which is character based. So my VB program will start it like `Process.Start("MyApp.exe")` and thus the /k switch won't work. Sorry for not being very clear.

Comment: @EricvanLoon, you can still call that application _via_ `cmd.exe`, as in the example in my previous comment and as now also shown in the updated answer. If you don't want to keep the `cmd.exe` session open, use `/c` in lieu of `/k`

Comment: Hi @mklement0 Your command indeed seems to work! I don't know what this `foo bar` exactly does, the only issue now is that these words are parsed to my application too, which results in an error. But the title is changed and it sticks, so major progress here!
My application MyApp uses two parameters: -id=userid -pa=password, so the syntax now is: `Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k title Test Text & c:\MyApp\MyApp.exe -id=readonly -pass=readonly foo bar")`
Thanks again for your help!!
Kind regards,
Eric

Comment: Glad to hear it, @EricvanLoon. `foo bar` are just _sample arguments_ passed to the sample executable, `some.exe`. Just remove them from your call.

Comment: Bummer, I just wasn't looking properly. :-( The `foo bar` causes MyApp to fail, which throws me back to the cmd window, which uses the changed title. As soon as I remove the words, MyApp runs successful and takes over the title and replaces is with it's own... So the title only works for the the cmd windows itself, not for any application which is started in it.

Comment: @EricvanLoon. Never mind `SetConsoleTitle` - I hadn't realized that you're calling from a GUI. However, the _combination_ of the approaches, as described in the answer seems to work: set the initial title via `title`, then, in your VB code, set that same title again after your application has launched, and since the titles are the same, even `cmd.exe` reverting to its window title when you select the window for instance will then show the desired title.

Comment: Hi @mklement0 First of all, thank you very much for thinking along!
I added a piece of code to my question above, to show you what the issue is when you use the SetWindowText for cmd. When the Form is loaded, it opens a cmd window (named My new title) and is starts (just as an example) PowerShell in it. At that point, the title is changed to `My new title - powershell.exe`. When you click Button1, the title is changed back to `My new title`, but if you select any character with your mouse, it changes back to `My new title - powershell.exe`, So it won't stick.
Thanks again for your help! Eric

Comment: @EricvanLoon, please see my update, which should solve that problem. To whoever deleted my original comment: it is only appropriate to do so _once the addressee has seen it_, at which point _both_ comments should be deleted. If the addressee never sees the comment about the update, they may never learn that the problem has been addressed, and if _only_ the previous comment is retained, future readers may mistakenly assume that there is still a problem.

Comment: Hi @mklemet0 You stated `set the initial title via title, then, in your VB code, set that same title again after your application has launched, and since the titles are the same` That is what my application does (see the example I added to my original question). It starts the application (in my example powershell) in a renamed window: `Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k title My new title & powershell.exe")` and afterwards I rename it again through the button:`SetWindowText(h_wnd, "My new title")`. But the name changes back to `My new title - powershell.exe` when you click anywhere within the window

Comment: @EricvanLoon, that' s why i amended my answer to also show a `/c` solution, which does _not_ have this problem (I thought it would be enough to ask you to read the amended answer; I didn't think I needed to spell it out here as well).

Comment: Hi mklement0 Sorry for the confusion and thanks for you patience.
With the /c it's indeed working now with PowerShell. But for the application I want to use in the end, it's not. Most likely because this application takes a bit longer to load than PowerShell, which is somehow undoing the title command changes...

Comment: @EricvanLoon, I've updated the answer to show a solution that works analogously to your PowerShell approach: it waits in a loop until the window title has changed. Of course, this assumes that your application sets its title only _once_, at startup.

Comment: Hi @mklement0, Again, thank you VERY much for your help and example code. I tested it with various tools (like ping.exe) and it works for all application, but not for the specific application I like to use. I think this application is explicitly updating the title after each user interaction, I can't explain otherwise... That still not explains why the title update _is_ permanent when it's done through a PowerShell Start-ThreadJob. Although it doesn't work for my specific application, I marked your reply as an answer. I really appreciate all the time you invested in answering my question! Eric

Comment: My pleasure, @EricvanLoon. Sorry to hear it still isn't working. One last thing you can try is to keep a loop on the VB.NET side going for as long as the application runs, and to keep calling `SetWindowText()` whenever a change in window title is detected.

Comment: Hi @mklement0, I thought about that solution too, but my VB form will start multiple instances of the application. I wouldn't know how to make a rename loop (which should run in the background as long as that copy of the application is active) and at the same time allow my form to start new instances.
So, my Form contains a Button1 and a Textbox1. The textbox contains the parameters for the application and a new instance of it is executed when Button1 is clicked. When I use a rename loop, I won't be able to start new instances, right? The form will wait for the loop to finish?
Regards, Eric

Comment: @EricvanLoon, you'd need to launch a _separate thread_ that monitors each launched instance.