# Change title of another window through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, titlebar, custom-titlebar

I have a VB application, which starts several instances of a third party non-GUI application. To keep track of these multiple instances, I update their title, using the `SetWindowText()` function. This application however has the nasty habit of continuously updating the title, so each SetWindowText works only temporary. As soon as you click anywhere in the screen, the tile is changed back.
I found a way to update the title through PowerShell, using the following code:

```
$titletext = "My Title"
# Start a thread job to change the window title to $titletext
$null = Start-ThreadJob { param( $rawUI, $windowTitle )
Start-Sleep -s 2
if ( $rawUI.WindowTitle -ne $windowTitle ) {
    $rawUI.WindowTitle = $windowTitle
}
}-ArgumentList $host.ui.RawUI, $titletext
& 'c:\Program Files\Application\Application.exe' '-id=userid -pass=password'
```

This works perfectly and the title change *is* permanent, so exactly what I want. The only problem is that *everything* is being logged in the Windows PowerShell log, including the parameters -id= and -pass=.
A solution would be if I can start application.exe through my VB application and do the rename through a PowerShell script, but  I don't know if that is possible through a ThreadJob.
Is it possible to start a ThreadJob and rename another window, maybe through it's handle?

Comment: You are hosting / running the CLI in Powershell, so all you really did is change the standard output stream of the application to your Powershell instance. If your Application is a Windows Application with GUI you can host all instances as MDI child windows within your own Application. If it does not provide any window to host, you can use C# and redirect the standard output to your own window or spawn mutliple windows and set each window as output for one application instance. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18577/How-to-redirect-Standard-Input-Output-of-an-applic

Comment: Hi @Max,
I have been down that road, but that won't be a solution for the application I'm starting from my VB form. The application I host is a command line application (no GUI) and it can sometimes generate a lot of output. It has a build-in option to display only one page of output at a time, as well as an option to cancel the rest of the output, like `Press enter to continue, c to cancel` When I redirect stdoutput in my VB application to an MDI child, I loose that feature and all output is send.

Comment: You can redirect output as well as input. Read the article I added above. You can do that from within VB as well. Powershell, VB, C# are all using the same framework. Everything you can do in one you can do in the other. You can redirect input and output for every command line application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Changing the console title from *inside* that console is your best bet, which is what your PowerShell code does.

  - While it is possible to call the [`SetWindowText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtextw) API function to set *another process'* console-window title, this *change isn't guaranteed to stay in effect*, because any subsequent *interaction* with such a window causes the *original*  window title to be restored (this behavior seems to be built into `conhost.exe`, the console host underlying regular console windows on Windows).
  - By contrast, setting the title of the console window associated with the *current process*,  *does* stay in effect (unless overridden again later), which is what the [`SetConsoleWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletitle) WinAPI function does (which shell- and API-based mechanisms such as `title` in `cmd.exe`, and `[Console]::Title` / `$hostUI.RawUI.WindowTitle` in PowerShell presumably ultimately call).
- Therefore, **stick with your PowerShell approach and avoid the password-logging problem with the help of an environment variable**, as detailed below.

---

- Windows PowerShell's script-block logging - see [about_Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logging?view=powershell-5.1) - logs the *source code* of code being created.

  - You can avoid argument *values* from being logged if you - instead of providing *literal* arguments - provide them *indirectly*, via *variables* that you set *from outside PowerShell*.
- Therefore:

  - Make your VB.NET application (temporarily) set an *environment variable* that contains the password. (Perhaps needless to say, storing and passing *plain-text* passwords is best avoided).
  - In your PowerShell script, refer to that environment variable instead of passing a *literal* password - that way, the actual password will *not* be shown in the logs.

For example, assuming that your VB.NET application has created environment variable `MYPWD` containing the password, before launching the PowerShell script:

```bash
$titletext = "My Title"

# Start a thread job to change the window title to $titletext
$null = Start-ThreadJob { param( $rawUI, $windowTitle )
  Start-Sleep -s 2
  if ( $rawUI.WindowTitle -ne $windowTitle ) {
    $rawUI.WindowTitle = $windowTitle
  }
} -ArgumentList $host.ui.RawUI, $titletext

# Note: 
# * Assumes that your VB.NET application has set env. var. "MYPWD".
# * The arguments must be passed *individually*, not inside a single string.
& 'c:\Program Files\Application\Application.exe' -id=userid "-pass=$env:MYPWD"
```

Comment: Hi @mklement0, Again thank you **very** much for your help! The option to use a user environment variable to pass the password to the PS script is working very well. I really appreciate your help, thanks!!!
Eric